# Searching for title of 1980s sci-fi movie that reminded me of Star Wars

Tags: story-identification, movie, space

In the 1980ies I saw a Sci-Fi movie on TV, but I am not able to identify it any more. What I recall: There was a young man teaming up with various aliens to fight an evil captain of a spaceship that was able to destroy whole planets. One of the aliens consisted of several facets and let one of them get captured so that it would get on board of the evil spaceship and be able to serve as a spy. But the alien was unable to stand pain and when the facet was tortured the facet died. The evil ship was finally destroyed by a female alien who directed its space fighter into the planet destroying weapon. <s>The evil soldiers reminded me of the ones in Star Wars.</s>

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Battle_Beyond_the_Stars

Comment: Yes, it is Battle Beyond the Stars. I guess the reason why the soldiers reminded me of Star Wars is that they actually were from Star Wars and my memory filed both under "planet destruction"...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Possibly *[Battle Beyond the Stars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Battle_Beyond_the_Stars)* (1980) produced by Roger Corman

> The farming world Akir is threatened by the tyrannical warlord Sador (John Saxon), who rules the sinister Malmori Empire and, his body parts deteriorating, is capturing and appropriating them from others. Sador's huge dreadnought, the Hammerhead, mounts a "Stellar Converter", a weapon that turns planets into small stars. He demands that the peaceful Akira submit to him when he returns in "seven risings of your red giant", or he will turn his Stellar Converter on their planet. Zed (Jeff Corey), last of the famous Akira Corsairs, is old and nearly blind. He suggests they hire mercenaries to protect their world. Since Akir lacks valuable resources, its people can offer only food and shelter in payment. Unable to go in person, Zed offers his ship for the job if they can find a pilot. The ship is fast and well-armed, but, despite its AI navigation/tactical computer Nell, cannot defeat Sador alone. Shad (Richard Thomas), a young man who has piloted the ship and is well known to Nell, volunteers for the recruiting mission.

....

> Later, Shad meets a set of five alien clones who share a group consciousness named Nestor. They admit their life is incredibly dull, since their whole race shares one mind. In order to be entertained, they have sent five members to join Shad's cause. Nestor does not require payment, saying they are completely self-sufficient....

I see Nestor's interrogation scene around an hour and a third into the film on the copy I found online. One of the Nestors specifically says "that facet has ended" after the glowing chainsaw is lowered to harvest his arm, although they then attempt control of the transplanted arm to kill Sador.

### Trailer

Found on a list of [11 Movies and TV Shows That Tried to Be Star Wars](https://www.denofgeek.com/tv/11-movies-and-tv-shows-that-tried-to-be-star-wars/)

Comment: Tried to be *Star Wars* and *The Magnificent Seven*