# SF movie where bad guy has body parts of vanquished enemies transplanted onto himself

Tags: story-identification, movie, b-movies

I'm trying to track down a science-fiction movie that I only remember fragments of.

The good guys consist of humans and various aliens, and the alien bad-guy leader has body parts of vanquished enemies transplanted onto himself as living trophies. At one point, a set of five telepathic aliens who share a single consciousness volunteers one of their number to be captured so that its arm will be transplanted onto the bad guy and they can use it to try to kill him.

(The human protagonist, when told about the idea, asks something like "don't you need all of your bodies to run your spaceship?" and is told "we always carry a spare.")

I suspect that it's a low-budget movie, maybe made for TV (I definitely saw it on TV), probably from the 1980s.

Comment: In roughly which year did you actually watch this?

Comment: Pretty sure it was some time in the 1980s, that's as close as I can get. :-(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Roger Corman's 1980 *[Battle Beyond the Stars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Battle_Beyond_the_Stars)*, also the answer [here](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/169275/can-anyone-remember-a-film-where-a-damaged-ship-cant-count-down-sequentially-du).

> The farming world Akir is threatened by the tyrannical warlord Sador (John Saxon), who rules the sinister Malmori Empire and, his body parts deteriorating, is capturing and appropriating them from others. Sador's huge dreadnought, the Hammerhead, mounts a "Stellar Converter", a weapon that turns planets into small stars. He demands that the peaceful Akira submit to him when he returns in "seven risings of your red giant", or he will turn his Stellar Converter on their planet. Zed (Jeff Corey), last of the famous Akira Corsairs, is old and nearly blind. He suggests they hire mercenaries to protect their world. Since Akir lacks valuable resources, its people can offer only food and shelter in payment. Unable to go in person, Zed offers his ship for the job if they can find a pilot. The ship is fast and well-armed, but, despite its AI navigation/tactical computer Nell, cannot defeat Sador alone. Shad (Richard Thomas), a young man who has piloted the ship and is well known to Nell, volunteers for the recruiting mission.

As per my answer to [Searching for title of 1980s sci-fi movie that reminded me of Star Wars](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/269217/23243), there is indeed a scene where one of Nestor's facets infiltrates as a spy, and has its arm cut off to be used by the Sador. Subsequently, the other facets of Nestor do seize control of the arm in an attempt to kill Sador.

Comment: Awesome! Thank you!